# Automate Install mysql-server and postfix remotely

Tags: python, automation, installation, fabric

I am running a Python script with Fabric which sent a bash script over remotely and execute.
The script will have to run over multiple remote servers automatically (without user interference).

But when I am installing these 2 package, there is a small complication of GUI interface prompt in the command line. This cause the bash script to 'hang', awaiting for user input to continue.

1. mysql-server (Prompting user for root password)
2. postfix (Prompting for some configuration setting)

Is there an alternative to configure the process without the GUI interface prompt in the command line?

Comment: Anyone know how I can did same thing on postfix? Thanks @jslopez! That works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In http://www.muhuk.com/2010/05/how-to-install-mysql-with-fabric/ it's described a solution to the installation of mysql-server, basically what you have to do is:

```
# password prompt 
while True:
    mysql_password = getpass('Please enter MySQL root password: ')
    mysql_password_confirmation = getpass('Please confirm your password: ')
    if mysql_password == mysql_password_confirmation:
        break
    else:
        print "Passwords don't match"

# set the value in debconf
with settings(hide('warnings', 'running', 'stdout', 'stderr'),
              warn_only=True):
    if not run('dpkg-query --show mysql-server'):
        sudo('echo "mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password password '
            '%s" | debconf-set-selections' % mysql_password)
        sudo('echo "mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password_again '
             'password %s" | debconf-set-selections' % mysql_password)
```